# How to simulate a loop in Hive Sql?

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I want to simulate a loop in Hive. The problem is that of link traversal.

**Raw Data:**

```
phone,name
1234,Sam
2345,John
3456,Max
7899,Sam
7899,Tim
8899,Tim
8898,Dan
8899,John
```

I am only interested in getting phone numbers.

If I take 1234,Sam and go to 7899,Sam that would be 1-hop because Sam used 7899 number too. Then if I go from 7899,Sam to 8899,Tim that would be 1-hop because 7899 was used by Tim and Tim also used 8899. Now where we started from, 1234, to where we are now, 8899, we are 2-hops away. I can do this with a shell script with loops but I am interested to find if this is possible to do purely in Hive. I want the loop to stop if any one criteria is met:

10 hops reached **OR** no new numbers detected

(If the conditions above are hard to implement, I can just have one condition - 10hops reached)

**Visual representation:**

```
1 hop:
1234 -> Sam
Sam linked to 7899
```

```
2 hops:
7899 -> Tim
Tim linked to 8899
```

so 1234 and 8899 are 2 hops away.

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: What you are describing as "hops" is implement in SQL databases as recursive CTEs.  Hive does not support them.  You will need to write an application loop to accomplish this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks! I was not aware of recursive CTEs. Even though hive doesn't support them, it is good to know.